Python - Multiprocessing and variables handover to each call (but in external function)
I would like to enhance question from In Python, how do I pass local variable values to multiprocessing library's Pool?
where I have similar problem as in related question, just enhanced that I call it from different file.
To example:
File1 Code:
import Code

result = Code.Main_Code()
print(result)

File2 Code:
from multiprocessing import Pool

def Multicore_Patterns_List_processor(args):

    Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, Pattern = args
    print(f"{Variable1=}, {Variable2=}, {Variable3=}, current pattern is {Pattern}")

def gen_args(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3):
    for p in range(10):
        yield Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, p

def Main_Code():
    Variable1 = 1
    Variable2 = 2
    Variable3 = 3
    MultiCores = 3
    print("Finish of simple code and start of heavy code in parralel")
    with Pool(processes=MultiCores) as pool:
        pool.imap(Multicore_Patterns_List_processor, gen_args(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    print("Finish of heavy code and continue of simple code")
    done = True
    return done

This is not working.
I'm trying to reach the state where I let python by processed by single processor, because code is simple and later in the "Code.py" file there is an heavier code which allow be processed in parallel and thanks to this fact to speed time for Local function be processed (as the function is processed several times 10). After this python should continue in single processor to finish simple code.
UPD: as Johny writes I didn't put the error here, sorry. So I also tried to run your correction, but lest focus on issue. I tried to record video during debugging where I sure ".map" instead of ".imap":
link: https://youtu.be/jIJnKaUrtRU
when I use the ".imap" I don't receive any error, code just skip the code in "Multicore_Patterns_List_processor" at all as nothing prints on terminal.

"This is not working" ...it would help if you explained in what way it is not working. Do you get an error? Wrong result? What is the result?

What is wrong with the code you've shown? It runs without any exceptions or error messages

Hi, may I kindly ask you to check if adding if __name__ == "__main__" to the Code_main.py will fix your issue, as I've proposed in my answer. Thx

I would propose to change the code a bit. Instead of imap use map. And  you don't need to do join and close if you are running Pool inside context (inside with statement). Otherwise it works fine.
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
...

    MultiCores = cpu_count()
    print("Finish of simple code and start of heavy code in parralel")
    with Pool(processes=MultiCores) as pool:
        res = pool.map(Multicore_Patterns_List_processor, 
                       gen_args(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3))

UPD: Another thing that was kind of obvious, but I've missed to note in my answer is that the code of the main thread is executed without being guarded by __name__ == "main" statement. When Python tries to create new processes it copies all your modules to each thread. After the modules being copied they get imported and execute everything that is not guarded by if __name__ == "main": statement. So thread that was basically created a moment ago starts triggering creation of other threads and then this process gets into an infinite loop.
Below is the fix your issue:
# Code_main.py
import Code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = Code.Main_Code()
    print(result)


Can you explain why these changes are expected to solve the OP's stated problem?

It is very early to say if this changes will solve OP's problem, because he didn't write what the error is. As I said in my answer his code doesn't produce any errors on my computer.

What you have said about imap versus map (in this particular case) is true but irrelevant

@SIGHUP irrelevant to what?

If it doesn't describe a specific error, generally the question should be closed rather than answered. See the Answer Well-Asked Questions section of How to Answer. (Thus, I assume "relevant" in SIGHUP's comment to be "relevant to solving any narrow, specific problem with the related code")

So we all agreed that this is one of the questions that will be closed sooner or later, because it actually doesn't have any reproducible errors.

@JohnnyCheesecutter Suggesting use of map() rather than imap() is a reasonable comment. As the "question" is, at the very least, vague, it's virtually impossible to provide any kind of answer pending more details. But that's just my opinion which doesn't usually count for much

Thanks for commenting on my answer. Everything make sense.

Hello all, thank you for all of yours reactions. I was able to make my code working with simple by writing this code "if name == "main":" at the beginning of all my procedures and using ".map" within "with" statement. Thank ou all.

as Johny writes I didn't put the error here, sorry. So I also tried to run your correction, but lest focus on issue. I tried to record video during debugging where I sure ".map" instead of ".imap":
link: https://youtu.be/jIJnKaUrtRU
when I use the ".imap" I don't receive any error, code just skip the code in "Multicore_Patterns_List_processor" at all as nothing prints on terminal.

Hi, could you please edit your question and add this information directly in the question. Thx!

Also I've updated my answer. Please read the details. Hope new fix will help. Cheers.
